# LibGDX unProject returns wrong values

Tags: java, libgdx

I am working on a game and I need to translate mouse coordinates to world coordinates. The problem is I can't unProject. When I click on origin it returns a value about ( 4,-61). Values are near to expected but not correct. What may be the problem?

Edit:

```
camera.position
```

Returns

> [0.0, -960.0, 0.0]

```
camera.unproject( new Vector3(Gdx.graphics.gedWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2, 0))
```

returns

> [319.99997, 238.99998, 0.0]

And when I click on the origin which I pointed with a rectangle unprojecting returns

> [0.77363586, -105.15996, 0.0]

My first attempt may be wrong but there is a problem with Y value of unprojecting when clicking on origin

Edit2:

Here is the simplest code which is problematic:

```
public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button){

    camera.update();

    lastTouch = camera.unproject(new Vector3(x, y, 0));

    return true;
}
```

Here position of lastTouch is not correct

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can take a look at the surrounding code please?

Comment: Are you aware that, as per the [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mouse,-touch-%26-keyboard#mouse--touch), mouse/touch events are relative to the upper left corner?

Comment: I will provide a mcve soon and yes I am aware that and unProject is used for that purpose

Comment: @PhilAnderson I have added the part which is problematic

Comment: Where are the x and y values coming from? The reason I ask is that camera.unproject() is very widely used, and basically works fine, so I'd be absolutely stunned if the problem really was in there. I'm trying to check what values you're passing in, and also what transforms you've made to the camera, in order to see where the problem really lies.

Comment: I do not do any transform to the camera and values come from the InputProccessor but I found where is the problem I will write an answer soon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

viewport#project should be called instead camera#project. That solved all the problems

Comment: Viewport#project calls Camera#project.. so it is the same

Comment: @ElSajko but it solved the problem, then you should share a better solution, right?